# Implement Camera Functionality like Genius Scan Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I want exactly the functionality of Camera (Like Single and Batch(Multiple Photos at a time)) in the following app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thegrizzlylabs.geniusscan.free&hl=en

I have implemented Successfully this. But, my question is, I have implemented this functionality with SurfaceView. When I capture photos from camera, its blurred when compared to the Genius Scan App.

Could anyone please let me know how exactly i can achieve this functionality without getting blurred.

**NOTE:** Capturing Multiple Photos

```
private void takeImage() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

            private File imageFile;

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                try {
                    // convert byte array into bitmap
                    Bitmap loadedImage = null;
                    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
                    loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                            data.length);

                    // rotate Image
                    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(rotation);
                    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,
                            loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),
                            rotateMatrix, false);
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    File folder = null;
                    if (state.contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        folder = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Demo");
                    } else {
                        folder = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Demo");
                    }

                    boolean success = true;
                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        success = folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                    if (success) {
                        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                        imageFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()
                                + File.separator
                                + new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString()
                                + "Image.jpg");

                        imageFile.createNewFile();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    // save image into gallery
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
                    fout.close();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                            imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    CameraDemoActivity.this.getContentResolver().insert(
                            Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                    if (mSingleView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        btnDoneClicked();
                    } else {

                    }


                    mArrayUri.add(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

                    if (mBatchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        batchClickCount++;
                        mtxtCapturedClicks.setText(String.valueOf(batchClickCount));
                    } else {
                        batchClickCount = 0;
                        mtxtCapturedClicks.setText("");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I stumbled over a similar problem once. Are you using the "data" extra in ```onActivityResult```? If you look at the [Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorial, that extra is simply a thumbnail, and you need to provide a file URI in the take picture intent to save the full sized image to.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    float scaleX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float scaleY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float pivotX = 0;
    float pivotY = 0;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotX, pivotY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Try this function to improve the image quality